# jQuery - Invalid Argument on removeClass with delay in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery 1.7 and jQuery UI 1.8.16

I made a js fiddle to show what I'm doing <strike>however it works fine.</strike> and it blows up in internet explorer.
http://jsfiddle.net/MEDtE/4/

I think it may be related to my usage of the ui-darkness theme but I don't see why.

I traced the problem to the jQuery cur function

```
cur: function () {
    if (this.elem[this.prop] != null && (!this.elem.style || this.elem.style[this.prop] == null)) {
        return this.elem[this.prop];
    }

    var parsed,
    r = jQuery.css(this.elem, this.prop);
    // Empty strings, null, undefined and "auto" are converted to 0,
    // complex values such as "rotate(1rad)" are returned as is,
    // simple values such as "10px" are parsed to Float.
    return isNaN(parsed = parseFloat(r)) ? !r || r === "auto" ? 0 : r : parsed;
}
```

`backgroundPositionY` apparently has a value of `top` from the `jQuery.css()` call and that value is returned.

jQuery thinks this value is a percentage and a NaN occurs.

Can I fix this?

Comment: Is the class you are trying to remove setting the backgroundPositionY? I'm not sure why else you bought it up otherwise... It sounds like it is trying to animate that and can't work out how to or something maybe...

Comment: @Chris I never touch backgroundPositionY and from what I can see the ui-darkness theme doesn't either. I don't know why it is in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved in jQuery 1.7.1.
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7915

Which came out on the 24th.... :-P

Answer (score 1):

I have had mixed results using setTimeout with browser animations.  I would keep this all within jQuery, and use jQuery's delay functionality.  That should keep it the same across all browsers.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myp').delay(500).removeClass('ui-state-highlight',1500);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This error is bubbling out of the removeClass call. The error still occurs. http://jsfiddle.net/PUbhJ/1/

Comment: had to switch to an IE browser and I could reproduce your error message.  sorry, i was in chrome when i wrote the solution

Answer (score 0):

whats that second argument doing there in removeClass. removeClass only takes 1 argument.

Comment: it's only in jquery ui. so maybe jquery ui is not included?